# Why is the row spilling out of div VERTICALLY?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.latestQuestions{
 height: 400px;
}

.latestQuestions .row{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="bg-info latestQuestions container">
    Latest Questions
    <div class="bg-primary h-100 row">
        <div class="col-sm">col1</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col2</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>OK</p>
```

I have a row inside a `<div>` and when I put background color to the row it spills out of the `<div>` vertically. I googled the solutions and all solutions are related to the horizontal spilling. I have used BootStrap latest version.

I have tried using `box-sizing: border-box;` Tried using `class="container"` in the outer div (It only helps in the horizontal spilling).

```css
.latestQuestions {
  height: 400px;
}

.latestQuestions .row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="bg-info latestQuestions container">
  Latest Questions
  <div class="bg-primary h-100 row">
    <div class="col-sm">col1</div>
    <div class="col-sm">col2</div>
    <div class="col-sm">col3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>OK</p>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCSzK.png)You can see that

OK

comes inside the color of the row. I want it outside and below that row.

Comment: Because `h-100` means `height:100%` which is 400px. Thus because you have additional text  ("Latest Questions") inside the container the **total** height is more than 400px leading to overflow.

Comment: @Paulie_D YES!! That must be it. But pls tell me how to solve that. OK should come below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the container a flex-column and then apply `flex:1` to the row (removing `h-100`).

There are Bootstrap classes `flex-column` etc that can help with this.

```css
.latestQuestions {
  height: 200px;
  /* adjusted for demo */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.latestQuestions .row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="bg-info latestQuestions container">
  Latest Questions
  <div class="bg-primary row">
    <div class="col-sm">col1</div>
    <div class="col-sm">col2</div>
    <div class="col-sm">col3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>OK</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove h-100 as its stands for `height: 100%` for block

```css
.latestQuestions{
 height: 400px;
}

.latestQuestions .row{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="bg-info latestQuestions container">
    Latest Questions
    <div class="bg-primary row">
        <div class="col-sm">col1</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col2</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>OK</p>
```